# BMO2 2019 Question 4 - Functions Problem

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Question:

Find all functions $f$ from the positive real numbers to the positive real numbers for which $f(x)\le f(y)$ whenever $x\le y$ and
$$
f(x^4)+f(x^2)+f(x)+f(1)=x^4+x^2+x+1
$$
for all $x>0$.

My progress:

Substituting $x=1$ gives $4f(1)=4$, so $f(1)=1$, and $f(x)\le 1$ when $x<1$ and $f(x)\ge 1$ when $x>1$. This also means that $f(x^4)+f(x^2)+f(x)=x^4+x^2+x$. Substituting $x=x^2$ gives $f(x^8)+f(x^4)+f(x^2)=x^8+x^4+x^2$, and so $f(x)-x=f(x^8)-x^8$, and knowing the value of $f(x)$ provides the values of $f\left(x^{8^n}\right)$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  I couldn't get any further than this in my attempt at the question.

Comment: A solution can be found [here](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/bmo2-2019/)

Comment: May I ask which BMO? British?

Comment: The BMO2 is the 2nd round of the British Maths Olympiad.